# Can we move particles along a mesh surface?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

Can we animate particles to move along a surface of a mesh? Maybe using Geometry nodes or something?
Something like this maybe
https://youtu.be/SYz3Pz0m2XM .
And it would be nice if we could set a offset from the mesh like it will track the ups and downs of the mesh surface but we can set a distance between the particles and the mesh.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the raycast node for that. The raycast node is "shooting" in a direction you define and you can use the hit points to set the position as you like.

node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]